# im trying to add a check box but i getting invalid hook call error how can i fix this?

Tags: react-native

i need to add this

const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);

and my checkbox is;

```
 <CheckBox
       value={isSelected}
       onValueChange={setSelection}

  />
```

Comment: please add the whole code.  there are many things that are not clear here. like are you importing useState right? are you using community checkbox. and onValueChange should be like this `onValueChange={(v)=>setSelection(v)}`

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);


 <CheckBox
    value={isSelected}
    onValueChange={(checked) => setSelection(checked)}
  />
```